# How to use Incron and date?

Tags: cron

I have the following code:

```
/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2015/09 IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /opt/imageopt$
```

how can i set the "/2015/09" part to todays date?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since replacing `/2015/09` with `"$(/bin/date +/%Y/%m)"` in your incron table entry breaks, create a system incron table (in `/etc/incron.d/`) and manipulate it directly with a root cron job (be generally careful with that). I.e. modify an incron system table entry automatically on a monthly basis to reflect the new date value `/YYYY/MM`.

```
$ sudo [yr-txt-editor] incron-daily-tab-update
#!/bin/bash
# script: incron-daily-tab-update  --  owned by root
currentpath=/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/"$(/bin/date +%Y/%m)"
/usr/bin/printf '%s' "$currentpath IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /opt/imageopt$" \
     > /etc/incron.d/imageopt.incron-rule
exit 0
```

Followed by:

```
$ sudo chmod ug+x incron-daily-tab-update
```

Then you have two possibilities:

1/ Move the script to `/usr/local/sbin/incron-daily-tab-update` and create a cron job to be run by root on the first of each month or ASAP afterwards at boot.

```
$ sudo crontab -e
@monthly /bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/incron-daily-tab-update
```

2/  move the script `incron-daily-tab-update` to `/etc/cron.monthly/`. The result will be the same as creating a crontab entry.

Either way add `root` on a line of its own to `/etc/incron.allow`; create that file if it does not exist on yr system.

From incrontab(5), *"incrontab files are read after any change"* so the change in path should be immediately detected by the `incrond` daemon and should have an immediate effect on the first boot of any given month...

Tell us how this goes.

Comment: won't work in incron.

Comment: @Hopelessone: o_0 ?! Can you explain what you tried ? What you got as a result ?

Comment: /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/"$(/bin/date +/%Y/%m)" IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /opt/imageopt$ and incron wont save it properly, comes out as /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/"$(/bin/date 0 IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /opt/imageopt$ after saving it.

Comment: @Hopelessone: answer modified, expanded.

Comment: Hi, anyway to do this without root cron job?

Comment: @Hopelessone: I know no easy way to do this without root privis, if only because /etc/incron.d is owned by root on usual Ubuntu like setups.  If not having root privileges  is a requirement , you definitely ought to have said so in your original question. -- Does the above work for you ? If it does, mark the answer as accepted, by selecting the green check mark left of the answer. Others may  benefit from it, if you do so.